# Can there be two different styles applied to a single component

Tags: java, html, gwt

```
HTML lb = new HTML();
lb.setHTML("Hi <BR> Thanks&Regards");
```

i know `lb.setStyleName("style");`
Now this "style" will appear for the entire lb component.

For some specific reason i need Hi to have a different style and Thanks & Regards to hav a different style.

I know that we have can two different labels and set two different text and styles But its creating problem to the logic .

Not sure whether this possible

Comment: In my opinion you can add separate tags for your text and apply styles on them.

Comment: Yea that's iam gonna try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should make it:

```
HTML lb = new HTML();
lb.setHTML("<span class='hi-style'>Hi</span> <BR> <span class='thanks-style'>Thanks&Regards</span>");
```